# Как при наведении на элемент выбрать его предыдущего соседа?

Tags: css, css3

Внизу пример кода знаю как выбирать следующие, но не понимаю как быть с предыдущими

с помощью js могу но интересует именно css

нужно чтобы при наведении поменялся фон

```css
.el {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">первый</div>
<div class="el">второй</div>
```

Comment: на css - никак.

Comment: css не умеет обращаться к родителям и надстоящим сестрам, можно имитировать (поменяв порядок скажем чере флоат), но зависит от задачи.

Comment: можна вот так - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0zvzuhhn/

Comment: @soledar10 ох уж эти костыли...)

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский - что есть то есть.

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо, но лучше я на js тогда))